# numpy.fromfile seems to be unable to read large files

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I wanted to write some very simple python helper tool for my project which is reading binary data from an ECG record. I have found somewhere that numpy.fromfile is the most appropriate tool to approach it, so I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import numpy as np

arrayOfNums = np.fromfile(sys.argv[1], 'short')
print("Converting " + sys.argv[1] + "...")

conversionOutput = open("output", "x")
conversionOutput.write(np.array2string(arrayOfNums, separator=' '))

conversionOutput.close()
print("Conversion done.")
```

I did that to write the data which is 2 byte records unseparated. The input file is somewhat large for a simple text file (over 7MB), however not large enough I think to cause numpy troubles.

The output I got in the file: [-32243 -32141 -32666 ... -32580 -32635 -32690]

Why the dots between? It seems to convert it okay, but omits almost everything it is supposed to save. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use the internationally accepted SI units. 7mb would be 7 millibits. 7MB is megabytes. A factor of around 8,000,000,000 different. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy reads correctly your file. To avoid a long display, numpy uses the dots:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(10000)
```

Output:

```
>>> a
array([0.20902653, 0.80097215, 0.06909818, ..., 0.5963183 , 0.94024005,
       0.31870234])

>>> a.shape
(10000,)
```

`a` contains 10000 values and not only the 6 displayed values.

**Update**

To display the full output:

```
import sys
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
print(a)
```

Comment: That's understandable, however how can I suppress this behaviour and make the display verbose?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?